# How to clear a specific overlay in map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I created the followings geopoint and items of an overlay

```
for(int i=0;i<_locationId.size();i++)
    {
    point = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(_latitudeToSave.get(i))*1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble(_longitudeToSave.get(i))*1E6));
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(new OverlayItem(point, _locationName.get(i),_locationId.get(i)+":"+_latitudeToSave.get(i)+":"+_longitudeToSave.get(i)));
    }
```

i have added my overlay like this

```
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

Now i have tried to remove the overlay by this

```
mapView.getOverlays().clear();
```

This clears off all the locations

but i need to remove a particular location... How to just remove one item from the overlay list?

And some times when i add an overlay item later then unless i press the map once the particular item does not get populated.. how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

map.getOverlays().remove(location)

Comment: I used map.getOverlays().remove(location) and it remove all overlays :(

Comment: I mean you must specify the location (ex: map.getOverlays().remove(4))
but if that does not work for you ...:s

Comment: Yes this doesnt work if i give 0 or 1 0r 2 any of them makes all of my items dissapear

Comment: I created different objects of itemized overlays and then removed it :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in the `GeoPoint` in place of the location for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

List mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

```
 public void removeChosenOverlay(String overlayUUID)
 {
     for(int i=0; i<mapOverlays.size(); i++)
     {
         String className = mapOverlays.get(i).getClass().getSimpleName();

         if(className.equals("MyOverlay"))
         {
             MyOverlay myOverlay = (MyOverlay) mapOverlays.get(i);

             if((myOverlay != null) && (myOverlay.getOverlayUUID.equals(overlayUUID)))
             {
                 mapOverlays.remove(i);
                 mapView.invalidate()
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```